# Convex hull length in C

Tags: c

Im making a program to calculate convex hull length of 2D points.

On the input there is a number of points `n` and then the coordinates of each point.

for example:

```
6
-8 -3
-6 1
-5 -2
-3 1
-3 4
2 18
```

and output is simply the length of the convex hull.

my code looks like this so far:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct point
{
    double x;
    double y;
}POINT,VECTOR;

POINT b[1000];
VECTOR normal;
int n;

int upper_lower(int i, VECTOR ab, double c) {
    double x, y,result;
    y = b[i].y;
    x = normal.x*b[i].x;
    result = -(x + c) / normal.y;
    if (y>result) return 1;
    if (y == result) return 0;
    else
        return -1;


}

int ccw(VECTOR v,VECTOR v2)
{
    double cp;

    cp = v2.x*v.y - v2.y*v.x;

if (cp == abs(cp)) return 1;
else
    return -1;


}

double vector_length(VECTOR v)
{
    return sqrt(pow(v.x, 2) + pow(v.y, 2));

}

int cmp_points(const void *p1, const void *p2)
{
    const POINT *pt1 = p1;
    const POINT *pt2 = p2;

// do primary compare on x
if (pt1->x > pt2->x)
    return 1;
if (pt1->x < pt2->x)
    return -1;

// pt1->x == pt2->x - do secondary compare on y...
if (pt1->y > pt2->y)
    return 1;
if (pt1->y < pt2->y)
    return -1;

// pt1 == pt2
return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int i,poloha,upper[1000],lower[1000],h=0,d=0;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    if (n <= 0 && n > 1000) return 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%lf %lf", &b[i].x, &b[i].y);
    }
    qsort(b, n, sizeof(POINT), cmp_points);

//split in half
VECTOR ab;
double c;
ab.x = b[n - 1].x - b[0].x;
ab.y = b[n - 1].y - b[0].y;
normal.x = -ab.y;
normal.y = ab.x;
c = -normal.x*b[0].x - (normal.y*b[0].y);
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    poloha = upper_lower(i,ab,c);
    if (poloha == 1) upper[h++] = i;
    if (poloha == -1) lower[d++]=i;
    if (poloha == 0)
    {
        upper[h++] = i;
        lower[d++] = i;
    }

}
int j = 0;
double v, length = 0;
VECTOR v1, v2, v3,v4;
v3.x = 0; v3.y = 0;
//lower part
for (i = 0; ; i++)
{
    int in = 0;
    if (lower[i + 2] < 0)
    {
        v1.x = b[lower[i + 1]].x - b[lower[0]].x;
        v1.y = b[lower[i + 1]].y - b[lower[0]].y;

        v2.x = b[lower[i]].x - b[lower[i + 1]].x;
        v2.y = b[lower[i]].y - b[lower[i + 1]].y;

        lenght += vector_length(v1);
        length += vector_length(v2);
        break;
    }
    v1.x = b[lower[i + 1]].x - b[lower[i]].x;
    v1.y = b[lower[i + 1]].y - b[lower[i]].y;

    v2.x = b[lower[i + 2]].x - b[lower[i]].x;
    v2.y = b[lower[i + 2]].y - b[lower[i]].y;
    in = ccw(v1, v2);
    if (in == 1)
    {
        length += vector_length(v1);
        v3 = v2;
        v4 = v1;
    }
    if (in == -1)
    {
        length -= vector_length(v4);
        if (v3.x != 0 && v3.y != 0)
        {
            length += vector_length(v3);
            v3.x = 0; v3.y = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            length += vector_length(v2);

        }


    }
}

printf("%.3lf", length);

return 0;
}
```

the problem is that in the last part where I try to compute the length...I just dont know how to finish it..no matter what I try it never works as I want to. Could you guys give me some advice?

Comment: Just find the convex hull using the standard algorithms. Then length is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see a standard answer, so here's the algorithm:

Choose a point roughly in the centre of your point cloud. Then sort the points radially, by angle from the centre. The topmost point must be in the convex hull, so define it as having an angle of 0.0 and being first in the list.

Now go though. Put point 2 in the "tentative" hull list. Then check point 3. If the angle P1-P2-P3 is concave (relative to the centre point), remove P2 from the list, if it is convex, keep it. Continue like this, backtracking and removing points if they go concave. You only need two points in your "tentative" list, once you have three, they become definite.

You stop when you go full circle and get back to P1.

Answer (score 0):

There are many known [convex hull algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms), one of the simplest of which is the [gift wrapping algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gift_wrapping_algorithm). Here's an implementation that fits in your program where the points have been input and sorted:

```
    int j = 0;  // after sorting, b[0] is leftmost point, must be on an edge
    double length = 0;
    VECTOR v1, v2, vv;
    v1.x = 0, v1.y = 1; // start by measuring angles from vertical
    int iv;     // index of next edge point
    do          // find next egde point by minimum angle
    {
        double lv1 = vector_length(v1), lv2, lv;
        double cv = -1; // minimal possible cosine value
        for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) if (i != j)
        {   // compute cosine of angle between v1 and (b[j]-->b[i]) = v2
            v2.x = b[i].x-b[j].x, v2.y = b[i].y-b[j].y;
            double c = (v1.x*v2.x + v1.y*v2.y) / lv1 / (lv2 = vector_length(v2));
            if (c > cv) cv = c, iv = i, lv = lv2, vv = v2;  // new maximum cosine
        }
        if (v == -1) break;
        // printf("%d:%f,%f-->%d:%f,%f = %f\n", j, b[j], iv, b[iv], lv);
        length += lv;
        v1 = vv;        // found edge is new reference edge
    } while (j = iv);   // repeat while not at start again
    printf("%.3lf\n", length);
```